# How to track the request size with RoundTrip?

Tags: http, go

Apologise for the potentially newbie question, but I'm adapting someone else's code and not familiar with the Go language.

In code that is proxying http requests I have the following segment

```
func handleHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    resp, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
..
```

I understand that req includes a streaming body, so no immediate length is available as I expect RoundTrip to read such stream. My question is how can I adapt such piece of code so that I can have a final size of the request body after the stream was fully consumed...

Thanks

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request` has a `ContentLength` as an available attribute, you might just be able to use that in some cases. Although if the request uses Tranfer-Encoding I think this value is set to -1 (maybe 0).

Otherwise I think you can wrap req.Body with your own io.ReadCloser implementation. Like so:

```golang
type RecordLengthReadCloser struct {
    io.ReadCloser
    length     int
}


func (rc *RecordLengthReadCloser) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := rc.ReadCloser.Read(p)
    rc.length += n
    return n, err
}

func handleHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    rc := &RecordLengthReadCloser{ReadCloser: req.Body}
    req.Body = rc
    resp, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
    fmt.Println(rc.length)
    _, _ = resp, err
}
```

This might have issues I'm unaware of, I'm not sure if you can freely re-assign the req.Body without issues.

Comment: After fixing a typo (readCloser->ReadCloser), worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: whoops, fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

`http.Request.Body` is of type `io.ReadCloser`. It is an `interface`, you can take advantage of this to wrap the Body value with your own implementation of `io.ReadCloser` that counts the bytes read from it.

```golang
package main_test

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func TestRequestLen(t *testing.T) {
    reqBody := "Hello world!"
    resBody := "Hello, client"
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, resBody)
    }))
    defer ts.Close()

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, ts.URL, strings.NewReader(reqBody))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Body = &bytesRead{ReadCloser: req.Body}

    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    greeting, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if want := resBody; string(greeting) != want {
        t.Fatalf("invalid response body %q want %q", string(greeting), want)
    }
    if want := len(reqBody); req.Body.(*bytesRead).total != want {
        t.Fatalf("invalid request length %v want %v", req.Body.(*bytesRead).total, want)
    }
}

type bytesRead struct {
    io.ReadCloser
    total int
}

func (c *bytesRead) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = c.ReadCloser.Read(p)
    c.total += n
    return
}
```